# Flexible-sized vertical text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a non-fixed-sized vertical text in CSS. What I did so far is here:

```css
.square-span {
  padding: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.square-span::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: calc(100% - 1em);
}

.vertical-wrapper {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(1em + 10px);
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-wrapper">
  <span class="square-span">
    <div class="square-content">Retweet</div>
  </span>
</div>
Hello World!
```

This works on Internet Explorer and Firefox but not on Chrome. The height of the text is incorrectly fixed on Chrome.

Please help me fix this or provide any other method to make vertical text **without any fixed size and JavaScript**.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `span`s should not contain `div`s. That's invalid HTML.

Comment: It's doable [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6n6pdgen/3/) but the problem comes when you try to use it in conjunction with other elements. Try adding another div the same to the fiddle and see,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is taken from [LINK](http://kizu.ru/en/fun/rotated-text/)

Don't forget to add '-wekkit-' and other prefixes for the `transform`: [CAN I USE IT](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

This solution makes use of `overflow:hidden;` with a float left on the pseudo element.

But the real trick is the `margin-top: 100%` because margin uses their parents height as the length unit.

```css
.square-span {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translate(0, 100%) rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: blue;
}
.square-span:after {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
.vertical-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<span class="vertical-wrapper">
  <span class="square-span">Retweeting a lot of text</span>
</span>
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: Great, I should have searched by "rotated text". Thanks! BTW, let's not forget to add unprefixed `transform`. :D